# pandas .loc returns inconsistent types

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Say I have 2 dataframes

```
df1= pd.DataFrame(["2020-12-31","2021-01-01"],columns={"date"},index=['23845940781720275',"23845940781720275"])
```

and

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(["2020-12-31"],columns={"date"},index=["23845940781720275"])
```

I want to get a way to enumerate the items in the "date" column for both cases:

- An index spans on several dates (df1)
- An index contains a unique date (df2)

When I try the following solutions I get inconsistent results

```
> type(df1.loc["23845940781720275"]["date"])

<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

> df1.loc["23845940781720275"]["date"]

23845940781720275    2020-12-31
23845940781720275    2021-01-01
Name: date, dtype: object

> type(df2.loc["23845940781720275"]["date"])

<class 'str'>

> df2.loc["23845940781720275"]["date"]

'2020-12-31'
```

I found some posts saying to use the `df.loc[x][['column']]` to always get a DataFrame, but then when I use it, I get the same level of inconsistency

```
> type(df1.loc["23845940781720275"][["date"]])

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

> type(df2.loc["23845940781720275"][["date"]])

<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

My IRL use case is made easier and more readable using `pandas`, any fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's because the second dataframe contains only 1 row and 1 column.

In the second case `type(df2.loc["23845940781720275"][["date"]])` -

you converted str to series. It's not a dataframe as it still contains only one column pointing to single series.

If you want to remove the inconsistency then use -

```
type(df2.loc[["23845940781720275"]][["date"]]) # pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

To fetch a list of dates for an index use -

```
df2.loc[["23845940781720275"]][["date"]]["date"].values.tolist()
```

Comment: Indeed, this seems to work in order to always return a dataframe. But the problem of selecting a list of `dates` for an index, how would you do it? (NB : Now the return type is always a dataframe, so we can't just fetch a series representing the dates for a given index)

Comment: @Aetos you can just add `.date.values.tolist()` to the end of the line above (without the `type()` part).  That will extract the date series object as a numpy array and convert it to list.

Comment: @AlexK yeah thanks, yours is a better fix than what I wrote in one answer bellow (more readable)

Comment: If one of you could write the completed answer I'll mark it as the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a (dirty) fix to extract the dates from the dataframes:

```
[date_str.strip() for date_str in df1.loc[['23845940781720275']][['date']].to_string().strip().split(f"\n{'23845940781720275'}")[1:]]
```

returns : `['2020-12-31', '2021-01-01']`

```
[date_str.strip() for date_str in df2.loc[['23845940781720275']][['date']].to_string().strip().split(f"\n{'23845940781720275'}")[1:]]
```

returns : `['2020-12-31']`